# C# - preparing event after pushing two buttons on keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard-events

i've got problem. If I push one key I can get event for example:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
            {
                Method();
            }
```

How could I do the same if I push two keys? For example Enter + F4?

Comment: Do you mean simultaneously, or press and release one, then the other?

Comment: if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) <<--- it is the answer like Mujassir Nasir has written below. thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    FormLoad()
{
   this.KeyPreview = true;
   this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
}

void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Works for Ctrl+F4
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
```

See if this work for you.